# iterate on 2D vector with C++

Tags: c++, vector

It's been years i didn't use C/C++ and i am trying to review the basics, i have an issue to iterate on a 3D vector:

```
#include        <string>
#include        <vector>
#include        <iterator>

int                                             main() {
  std::vector< std::vector<std::string> >       container;
  std::vector<std::string>                      table;
  std::string                                   line;

  for (int container_it = 0; container_it < 2; container_it++) {
    for (int table_it = 0;  table_it < 5 ; table_it++) {
      line = "TEST";
      table.push_back(line);
    }
    container.push_back(table);
  }


  for (std::vector< std::vector<std::string> >::iterator container_it = container.begin(); container_it != container.end(); container_it++)
    for (std::vector<std::string>::iterator it = (*container_it)->begin(); it != (*container_it)->end(); it++)
      std::cout << *it << std::endl;
}
```

i get the errors:

```
base operand of ‘->’ has non-pointer type ‘std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >’
base operand of ‘->’ has non-pointer type ‘std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >’
```

Comment: I see two dimensions...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with chris, I only see 2 dimensions here and the code has some syntax errors but it looks like this line:

```
for (std::vector<std::string>::iterator it = (*container_it)->begin(); it != (*container_it)->end(); it++)
```

should be:

```
for (std::vector<std::string>::iterator it = (*container_it).begin(); it != (*container_it).end(); it++)
```

or more simply:

```
for (std::vector<std::string>::iterator it = container_it->begin(); it != container_it->end(); it++)
```